# IBM Mobilefirst 8 with Websphere application server using oob derby database

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, derby, websphere-8

Installed IBM Mobilefirst 8 server with WAS 8.5.5.12 using Apache derby database.

Facing below error while checking connection of datasource which are created for mobilefirst server :

```
java.lang.Exception: DSRA8101E: DataSource class cannot be used as one-phase: ClassCastException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver40 incompatible with org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver
```

Working fine with mysql database.

Comment: use printStackTrace to get the full stack trace of the exception. It's odd because both of those are internal classes which are not classes you'd expect clients of Derby to be manipulating in their code.

Answer (score 0):

While this message would normally indicate that a data source implementation class was specified that does not implement javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource, I don't believe that is the case here based on the classes identified in the exception message. Another possible cause is that multiple copies of the Derby JDBC driver are on the classpath at the same time.  It should be noted that WebSphere Application Server traditional ships a copy of the Derby JDBC driver.  If you do have two copies, is it possible to switch to only using the one that is shipped with the application server?  If that is not possible, you might be able to work around this by selecting the option to isolate your JDBC provider.

Answer (score 0):

For use with MFP 8.0 standalone server with Websphere Application Server 8.5.5.5, use DB2,MySQL or Oracle